# How to design a custom menu in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I was asking myself how could I design a "menu" in my application? To be more specific, I have in mind a game, and I would like to "pop-up" a menu, lets say a square, from the left corner, so that I can still see the activity under. My question is if I have to full-redesign a dialog, or there is a way to create a new activity and style it to not take the full screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into the **android.widget.PopupWindow** class?  It will appear on top of your current Activity so you don't need a new one.  You can read about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: thanks alot, really seems what I needed. I'll have a look as soon as possible